# Пароль для бота Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot

Можно ли как-то поставить пароль на бота в Telegram?
А то получается, что им может управлять любой, кто знает его логин.

Comment: Вы можете задать вопрос пользователю и если он неправильно ответит, то прекратить беседу

Comment: @VenZell, Спасибо! Сейчас буду писать) А как Ваш комментарий сделать ответом на этот вопрос?

Comment: @VenZell, Еще такой вопрос, не подскажите случайно команду которая обрывает связь с ботом?

Comment: Если бы знал как именно это сделать, написал бы ответ. Что это сделать можно знаю точно.

Comment: @VenZell, Спасибо еще раз! Буду искать. Если найду, отвечу на вопрос.

Comment: Возможно подойдет https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.deleteChatUser

Comment: @VenZell это метод не из Bot API, а из Telegram API. Немого разные вещи

Comment: Если на ваш вопрос дан ответ, вы можете его пометить как правильный, установив зеленую галку слева от ответа под кнопками для голосования. Или написать свой ответ и отметить его как правильный.

Answer (score 2):

```
users = [123, ..., ..., n]  # chat id

# Органичение доступа к боту по ID
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id not in users)
def some(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Извините, Создатели не разрешают мне общаться с незнакомыми пользователями)
```

ну и вдруг пригодится это

```
users_start = [123, 456, -100]  # последнее - id группы если бот что-то должен делать в группе
# Органичение выполнение команды start
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id not in users_start, commands=['start'])
def some(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'У Вас нет прав на выполнение данной команды')
```

Answer (score 1):

Создайте массив пользователей, указавших пароль

```
let logged_in_users = []
```

При получении нового сообщения, проверяйте есть ли ID пользователя в созданном ранее массиве

```
if (logged_in_users.includes(message.from.id))
```

Если да, пусть бот обработает сообщение

Иначе, пусть бот сверит текст сообщения с паролем

```
if (message.text == 'password')
```

Если да, добавьте ID пользователя в массив и обработайте сообщение

```
logged_in_users.push(msg.from.id)
```

Если нет, отправьте сообщение о том, что требуется ввести верный пароль

Answer (score 0):

Задача решается игнорированием сообщений от пользователя с определённым *chat_id*. Для этого нужно хранить их все и устанавливать флаг блокировки там, где это потребуется. Хранение *chat_id* полезно и для многих других задач.

---

**Пример** (*псевдокод*):

```
while (true)
 {
  var updates = GetUpdates();
  foreach update in updates
   {
    var chat_id = update.chat.id;
    if chat_id in (%list_of_blocked_users%) then continue;
    //else do something with update
    ...
   }
 }
```

Comment: Так а как я могу знать chat_id пользователя заранее? Ведь лучше и проще сделать просто доступ для "своих", зная их chat_id.
Забыл указать в вопросе, что пишу на Python. Но в принципе Ваша идея мне понятна. Я придумал сделать следующим образом: 
1) Когда боту поступает команда /start, он здоровается и говорит "Для продолжения введите пароль"
2) Пароль я думаю можно присвоить какой нибудь переменной например - "passwd=12345"
3) Если пароль равен passwd, перейти к следующей функции def, в ином случае сделать return(возврат к началу).
Попытки написания этого кода продолжаются...

Comment: Кстати говоря, есть такая штука, как [Deep linking](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking). Возможно это будет самым оптимальным решением

Comment: А "своих" chat_id откуда знаете? Вот оттуда же узнавайте и чужих. С паролем идея в принципе рабочая, но какая-то не элегантная, мягко скажем. Изобретаете велосипед. Заранее знать не нужно, нужно записывать все chat_id и помечать флагами те, которые спамят/пытаются сломать бота/используют не по назначению/ и тп, определите логику бана сами

Comment: так добавьте команду /password и добавляйте chat_id в белый список